App Status: Rejected google play console how can fix it?
I have an application that was programmed in Flutter language, and after uploading it to Google, it was rejected. This is Google’s message to me. Can you help me with guidance on how to fix the error?

I changed the description but that didn't fix the error. I changed the privacy policy link but still the same error remains.  I changed the description but that didn't fix the error. I changed the privacy policy link but still the same error remains. thanks

The problem was solved after writing an accurate description of the application and its functions.
